# Need to Know How the Event is passed between sibling controllers in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that the broadcast and emit event happens like :
broadcast : from parent to child (Top to bottom )

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl1'>

    <div ng-controller='ctrl2'>

    <div>
</div>
```

1. To communicate from ctrl2 to ctrl1, 
   use emit,
2. To communicate from ctrl1 to ctrl2, 
   use broadcast,

Then How the events are passed when there is no nesting kind of controllers , I mean when there are routes

$routeProvider.when(..., controller :ctrl)

$routeProvider.when(..., controller: ctr2)

And How the Communication between this kind of structure happens.

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl1'>

    <div ng-controller='ctrl2'>

    <div>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl3'>

    <div>
 </div>
```

Hope I many is valid and make sense,

please provide me the explanation. along with answers, Thanks a lot

Comment: as variant - use `ctrl1` scope for communication

Answer (score 0):

From the Angular [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#!):

`$broadcast`:

> Dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.
>
> The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $broadcast was called. All listeners listening for name event on this scope get notified. Afterwards, the event propagates to all direct and indirect scopes of the current scope and calls all registered listeners along the way. The event cannot be canceled.

`$emit`:

> Dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.
>
> The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $emit was called. All listeners listening for name event on this scope get notified. Afterwards, the event traverses upwards toward the root scope and calls all registered listeners along the way. The event will stop propagating if one of the listeners cancels it.

So, the basic differences here are that `$broadcast` sends messages *down* the hierarchy, and cannot be cancelled, while `$emit` sends messages *up* the hierarchy, and can be cancelled.

In case of siblings, one option is to `$emit` a message the parent is listening to, have the parent cancel the event, then `$broadcast` a message the siblings are listening to.

However, in general, you will find that your code is more testable and more maintainable if you are able to eliminate uses for `$broadcast` and `$emit` completely wherever possible, perhaps by using a shared service.